# Different optimizations in Math.Sum in Win32/64

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have the following code

```
const
  NumIterations = 10000000;
var
  i, j : Integer;
  x : array[1..100] of Double;
  Start : Cardinal;
  S : Double;
begin
  for i := Low(x) to High(x) do x[i] := i;

  Start := GetTickCount;
  for i := 1 to NumIterations do S := System.Math.Sum(x);
  ShowMessage('Math.Sum: ' + IntToStr(GetTickCount - Start));

  Start := GetTickCount;
  for i := 1 to NumIterations do begin
    S := 0;
    for j := Low(x) to High(x) do S := S + x[j];
  end;
  ShowMessage('Simple Sum: ' + IntToStr(GetTickCount - Start));
end;
```

When compiled for Win32 Math.Sum is considerably faster than the simple loop, as Math.Sum is written in Assembler and uses four-fold loop unrolling.

But when compiled for Win64, Math.Sum is considerably *slower* than the simple loop, because in 64-bit Math.Sum uses Kahan summation. This is an optimization for accuracy minimizing pile-up of errors during the summation process, but is considerably slower than even the simple loop.

I.e. when compiling for Win32 I get code optimized for speed, when compiling the same code for Win64 I get code optimized for accuracy. This is not exactly what I naively would expect.

Is there any sensible reason for this difference between Win32/64? Double is always 8 byte, so the accuracy should be identical in Win32/64.

Is Math.Sum still implemented identically (Assembler and loop unrolling in Win32, Kahan summation in Win64) in current versions of Delphi? I use Delphi-XE5.

Comment: Probably in 32 bit the naive is reasonably accurate because the arithmetic is done using 80 bit x87 registers. In a real world setting I doubt you'd observe any performance difference because the time to access main memory will swamp the extra FP ops of Kahan sum. Your benchmark is very unrealistic because the data set is so small it will fit in L0 cache. I have learnt the hard way that using such micro benchmarks to optimise code is usually a giant waste of time for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Math.Sum still implemented identically (Assembler and loop unrolling in Win32, Kahan summation in Win64) in current versions of Delphi? I use Delphi-XE5.

Yes (Delphi 10.3.2).

> Is there any sensible reason for this difference between Win32/64? Double is always 8 byte, so the accuracy should be identical in Win32/64.

32-bit Delphi for Win32 uses the old FPU, while the 64-bit compiler uses SSE instructions. When the 64-bit compiler was introduced in XE2, many of the old assembly routines was not ported to 64-bit. Instead, some routines were ported with similar functionality as other modern compilers.

---

You can enhance the 64-bit implementation a bit by introducing a [Kahan summation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm):

```
program TestKahanSum;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,Math,Diagnostics;

function KahanSum(const input : TArray<Double>): Double;
var
  sum,c,y,t : Double;
  i : Integer;         
begin
    sum := 0.0;                 
    c := 0.0;                      
    for i := Low(input) to High(input) do begin
      y := input[i] - c;  
      t := sum + y; 
      c := (t - sum) - y; 
      sum := t;                 
    end;
    Result := sum;
end;

var
  dArr : TArray<Double>;
  res : Double;
  i : Integer;
  sw : TStopWatch;
begin
  SetLength(dArr,100000000);
  for i := 0 to High(dArr) do dArr[i] := Pi;
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  res := Math.Sum(dArr);
  WriteLn('Math.Sum:',res,' [ms]:',sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  res := KahanSum(dArr);
  WriteLn('KahanSum:',res,' [ms]:',sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  res := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(dArr) do res := res + dArr[i];
  WriteLn('NaiveSum:',res,' [ms]:',sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

---

64-bit:

```
Math.Sum: 3.14159265358979E+0008 [ms]:492
KahanSum: 3.14159265358979E+0008 [ms]:359
NaiveSum: 3.14159265624272E+0008 [ms]:246
```

32-bit:

```
Math.Sum: 3.14159265358957E+0008 [ms]:67
KahanSum: 3.14159265358979E+0008 [ms]:958
NaiveSum: 3.14159265624272E+0008 [ms]:277
```

Pi with 15 digits is `3.14159265358979`

The 32-bit math assembly routine is accurate to 13 digits in this example, while the 64-bit math routine is accurate to 15 digits.

---

Conclusion:

- The 64 bit implementation is slower (by a factor of two compared to a naive summation), but more accurate than the 32-bit math routine.
- Introducing an enhanced Kahan summation routine improves performance by 35%.

Answer (score 1):

Having the very same RTL function not behave the same when switching a compilation target is an awful bug. It should not change the behavior. Even worse, Win64/pascal Sum() over single or double does not behave the same! sum(single) is naive summing, whereas sum(double) uses Kahan... :(

You would better either use plain `+` operator, or create your own Kahan sum function.

I can confirm that the bug is still there in Delphi 10.3.

Comment: Do they really behave so differently? I mean the naive sum with 80 bit precision is probably more accurate than the Kahan sum at 64 bit precision. How would you go about matching the x87 80 bit precision with 64 bit SSE2 arithmetic? Given that the underlying hardware is different I think it is unrealistic to expect identical behaviour.

Comment: They will behave differently for sure, e.g. on double values. Just add a lot of small values to a huge value, and the Kahan and the naive addition won't match. Adding using the same precision should be identical - with x87 and SSE. BTW Kahan over double has a precision of more than 100 bits - much more than extended.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that Kahan is so accurate.

Comment: BTW x87 "extended" precision when working with integers (which is what Kahan is about) is not 80-bit, but 64-bit - what is called the "significand". "double" significand precision is 53-bit. The Kahan sum over double uses an addition "carry" register, so is expected to handle up to 53*2 = 106-bit integer precision when both registers are involved.